# Android SDK Connect to Web Server on Host

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am building a web service, and an android app to utilize it.  I am doing both through Eclipse.  When I'm running the web server locally, I can connect from my host machine's web browser at http://localhost:8888/.  How can I connect to that from my android app running on the emulator on the same machine?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How can I connect to that from my android app running on the emulator on the same machine?

If you are referring your localhost on your system from the Android emulator then you have to use `http://10.0.2.2:8888/`. Because Android emulator runs inside a Virtual Machine(QEMU) therefore here `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` will be emulator's own loopback address.

Refer: [Emulator Networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: Thanks, will try this tonight and report back!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not connect through localhost. Try to access it though IP address. Because, emulator and Machine making a network.