# Connection from Android Emulator to MYSQL Data base Error

Tags: android

i am trying to insert Latitude and Longitude value in mysql data base but it show the following error

1. **Error in http connection
   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to 
   **http://localhost*** refused*

   ```
   //My main.java code is :

   public void insertdata()
   {
   ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lat","34"));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Lon","72"));

   //http post
   try{
       HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpPost httppost = new      
      HttpPost("http://localhost/androidconnection/insertdata.php");
       httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
       HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
       HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
       InputStream is = entity.getContent();
       Log.i("postData", response.getStatusLine().toString());
   }

   catch(Exception e)
   {
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
   }
   ```

   }

   //at server side my php insertion code is "insertdata.php"

   ```
    <?php
       mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("PeopleData");
      //retrieve the data
      $lat = $_POST['lat'];
     $lon = $_POST['lon'];

     $sql = "INSERT INTO coords (Lat, Lon) VALUES('$lat', '$lon')";

          if (!mysql_query($sql, $sqlCon))
       {
           die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
      else
       {
         //echo "1 record added";
          }

               ?>
   ```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114301/android-sdk-connect-to-web-server-on-host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localhost` refers to the current machine on which the code is running, which in this case is Android phone(or emulator). **And in order to access the host computer from android emulator, you can use the ip address: 10.0.2.2**

Change your url as follows:

The line `HttpPost("http://localhost/androidconnection/insertdata.php");`
should look like this : `HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/androidconnection/insertdata.php");`

Comment: ok i used your solution but now in log cat i am getting this      postData HTTP/1.1 200 OK      while no data have been inserted in MYSQL yet

Comment: please see my above comments, now it does't give any error but data is not inserted in data base

Comment: @PirFahimShah Have you checked server logs? Also create log points in your php code, to see if the request reaches the server.

Comment: Ok i got it, actually if you see at my php server side code , there i have't any connection string value to a $sqlCon, now its working 100%, thanks a lot for your valuable code and advice

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert

```
localhost
```

with your

```
web server IP Address.
```

here, `HttpPost("http://localhost/androidconnection/insertdata.php");`

Also make sure about you have added `Internet` permission in your Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope it helps you.

Thanks.