# phonegap + php does not work

Tags: javascript, php, android, cordova

i want to load text from php in phonegap with eclipse and android emulator.
I do not know what I'm doing wrong.

my code index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script>
       var xmlhttp;
       window.onload = function(){
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);
       };

       function init(){
         var url = "http://localhost/php-handyAPP/phpinfo.php";
         xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
           alert ( xmlhttp.readyState);
           if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.readyState == 200)
           {
              document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           } else {
               document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Error loading page ";
             }
         };
         xmlhttp.open("GET", url , true);
         xmlhttp.send(null);
     };
     </script>
     <title>phonegap + php</title>
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="result"></div>
    </body>

</html>
```

my php code - phpinfo.php:

```
<?php
echo 'Hello World';
?>
```

my config.xml

```
 <access origin="*"/>
```

my AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I get from if statement  "Error loading page" in android emulator.

Comment: Probably since the url contains localhost, the website is only running on your pc and can't be reached from within your network or the internet.

Comment: You are most likely making a cross domain request, which naturally fails. Check out the [Same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) and adjust your phonegap and xmlhttp request URLs.

Answer (score 0):

PhoneGap does not have a PHP server.

In the code you are attempting to load a php page located at localhost: `var url = "http://localhost/php-handyAPP/phpinfo.php";`

Localhost in that case is your emulator, and I guess that emulator does not have a PHP server on it.

If PHP is hosted on your local machine (where emulator is ran from), then you could try:

`var url = "http://10.0.2.2/php-handyAPP/phpinfo.php";` instead, but I am not promising it will work.

Possible duplicate: [Android SDK Connect to Web Server on Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5114301/android-sdk-connect-to-web-server-on-host)

Comment: my PHP(xampp). is hosted on my machine (where the emulator also is running). you're right it does not work with 
var url = "http://10.0.2.2/php-handyAPP/phpinfo.php";     
or  
var url = " http://127.0.0.1/php-handyAPP/phpinfo.php";

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code in php file you are going to call

`<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>`

Add it and it will work for sure.

Comment: i have test it, but unfortunately does not work again.

Comment: try it with ajax jquery it wiill work I dont know javscript ajax so try to do with that.